# How to get the no of members in a tuple

Tags: c++, std

How to get the no of elements in a tuple. So that I can do the below.

```
for(int i=0;i<tuple.count();++i)
    cout << std::get<i>(tuple) << endl;
```

EDIT: My question is tuple size, not iterate over it's members. That is another subject. So the core point is getting tuple size. Iterating over is extra. So it is not duplicate of the question you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size will help you

Comment: `std::apply([](const auto&... e){ ((std::cout << e << std::endl), ...); }, tuple);`

Comment: Please read documentation before asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tuple_size` to know size of **tuple**

```
int size = tuple_size<decltype(mytuple)>::value; // size of tuple
```

Update:

In order to use values of tuple it needs to be known at compile time, not at runtime.
So you can't use **loop** directly.

Rather than you can use `get<0>(mytuple), get<1>(mytuple), get<2>(mytuple)` for each index value.

Comment: But `i` in `std::get<i>(tuple)` is a template parameter. Therefor it needs to be known at compile-time. So you can not iterate through with a `for` loop.

Comment: Using index_sequence with fold expression could do the access, see [example here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)